# WELD-001408 when trying to deploy rest project as war type that references a jar project with jpa content

Tags: java, ejb, jax-rs, weld, payara

When I try to deploy my JavaEE 7 war project on a payara 4.1.1 server the following error occurs:

> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type RatingEJB with qualifiers @Default at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private rest.resources.RatingResource.persistenceBean at rest.resources.RatingResource.persistenceBean(RatingResource.java:0) .

The stracktrace is as follows:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type RatingEJB with qualifiers @Default
at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private rest.resources.RatingResource.persistenceBean
at rest.resources.RatingResource.persistenceBean(RatingResource.java:0)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:355)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:277)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:130)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:151)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:494)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:480)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:455)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:454)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:90)
at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:226)
at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:329)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:220)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:487)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:263)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:234)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:285)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:136)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:384)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:316)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:466)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:169)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is my project structure

[project structue 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNrsx.png)

[project structue 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW94I.png)

This is the resource class from the war project:

```
package rest.resources;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

import persistance.ejb.RatingEJB;
import persistance.entities.Personalization;
import persistance.entities.Rating;
import rest.domain.RatingCollection;
import rest.domain.RatingDetails;
import rest.factory.RatingCollectionFactory;

@Stateless
@Path("/ratings")
public class RatingResource implements IRatingResource
{
@Context
private UriInfo uriInfo;

@Inject
private RatingEJB persistenceBean;

@Inject
private RatingDetailsFactory detailsFactory;
@Inject
private RatingCollectionFactory CollectionFactory;

@Override
public Response get(int start, int size)
{
    RatingCollection collection = null;

    List<RatingDetails> details = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Rating> list = persistenceBean.findAll(start, size);

    if (list != null)
    {
        Iterator<Rating> iterator = list.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Rating rating = iterator.next();
            RatingDetails ratingDetails = detailsFactory.createDetail(uriInfo, persistenceBean.create(rating), rating.getId());

            details.add(ratingDetails);
        }
        collection = CollectionFactory.createCollection(details, uriInfo, size, start);
    }

    return Response.ok(collection).build();
}

}
```

Here is the ejb class from the jar

```
package persistance.ejb;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import persistance.entities.Rating;

@Stateless
public class RatingEJB implements IPersistanceBean<Rating>
{
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "feedback")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
public Rating find(Object id)
{
    return em.find(Rating.class, id);
}

@Override
public List<Rating> findAll(int start, int size)
{
    TypedQuery<Rating> query = em.createQuery("SELECT r FROM Rating r", Rating.class);
    query.setFirstResult(start).setMaxResults(size);

    return query.getResultList();
}

@Override
public Rating create(Rating rating)
{
    em.persist(rating);

    return rating;
}

@Override
public void remove(Object id)
{
    em.remove(em.find(Rating.class, id));
}

@Override
public Rating update(Rating item)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

And here are the poms of the projects

parent:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>feedback</groupId>
<artifactId>feedback-parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>feedback-parent</name>
<modules>
    <module>feedback-persistance</module>
    <module>feedback-rest</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <version.java>1.7</version.java>
    <version.maven.clean.plugin>2.4.1</version.maven.clean.plugin>
    <version.maven.war.plugin>2.4</version.maven.war.plugin>
    <version.maven.compiler.plugin>3.1</version.maven.compiler.plugin>
    <version.maven.exec.plugin>1.2.1</version.maven.exec.plugin>
    <javaee.api.version>7.0</javaee.api.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Java EE -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javaee.api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>rest</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>feedback</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.maven.clean.plugin}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.maven.compiler.plugin}</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${version.java}</source>
                    <target>${version.java}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.maven.war.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

feedback-psersistance:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>feedback</groupId>
    <artifactId>feedback-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>feedback-persistance</artifactId>
<name>feedback-persistance</name>

<build>
    <finalName>feedback-persistance</finalName>
</build>
```

and feedback-rest

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>feedback</groupId>
    <artifactId>feedback-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>feedback-rest</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>feedback-rest</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>rest</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>feedback</groupId>
        <artifactId>feedback-persistance</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:\Users\user\workspace_neon\feedback-parent\feedback-persistance\target\feedback-persistance.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>feedback-rest</finalName>
</build>
```

So, what is wrong with my implementation? I'm new to JavaEE and everything I found on the web didn't work.

Thanks in advance.
Rudi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem. The solution was to create an ear project that includes the jar and the war project. Now I can deploy the ear project at the payara server and query the database from my rest services.

Here is the pom of the ear project

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>feedback</groupId>
    <artifactId>feedback-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>feedback-ear</artifactId>
<packaging>ear</packaging>
<name>feedback-ear</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>feedback-persistance</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>feedback-rest</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <version>7</version>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                <skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars>
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>feedback-rest</artifactId>
                    </webModule>
                    <ejbModule>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>feedback-persistance</artifactId>
                    </ejbModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: It is not necessary to bundle your application as an EAR to solve your problem. I guess that maven didn't bundle the REST project into the WAR project, into `WEB-INF/lib`. Try removing `<scope>system</scope>` and `<systemPath>...` as it does not make sense to use it. The default values are more standard, maybe even required for maven to bundle the ejb-jar into the WAR.

Comment: The `<scope>system</scope>` was necessary, because I didn't had access to the remote  repo at this moment. Without the ear packaging the persistance classes were not visible to the web project. As I said, I'm new to JavaEE, but to simply remove the ear packaging doesn't resolve my problem...

Comment: An alternative to `<scope>system</scope>` is to deploy the artefact into [your local maven repository](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html). Then you don't have to change the pom.xml definition. I wonder, if that helps.